# Checking if a radio button is checked serverside using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am displaying a form to a user with some content and a few radio buttons. How can I know which radio button is checked on server-side after user clicks on submit button in form?

I don't know why it has been marked negative. I searched on google about it but could find nothing. If it is not possible just say can't be done otherwise tell me how it could be done. I am posting some code but I don't think that would help

```
<input type="radio" name="meme" id="woman" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="woman"><img class="memeimage" src="url1" alt=""/></label>
<input type="radio" name="meme" id="man" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="man"><img class="memeimage" src="url2" alt=""/></label>
```

Should the PHP code be something like

```
if(empty($_REQUEST['meme'])) but how will that tell me which radio button is checked.
```

Comment: Give name to radio. You can simply check them with request like `$_POST['meme']`

Comment: Both of them have name meme how can I know which one was checked?

Comment: add a values to inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give radio button **value** like:

```
<input type="radio" name="meme" id="woman" class="input-hidden" value="woman"/>
<input type="radio" name="meme" id="man" class="input-hidden" value="man"/>
```

If you use this:

```
$_REQUEST['meme']// output man / woman
```

You can check like this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['meme'])) {
  //radio selected
  echo $_REQUEST['meme'];// will output man / woman
} else {
echo "nothing was selected.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `value` attribute to input

```
<input type="radio" name="meme" id="woman" class="input-hidden" value='woman' />
```

then

check value using `$_POST['meme']`